# Outputting a sorted list of pairs in scheme recursively (issue with base case)

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to sort and print out a list somewhat like this:

Apple : 1
Banana : 2
...etc (each pair is on a new line, but stackoverflow shows it like this)

I find that I can get it mostly done, but I get an error that it expects a pair, while it is given an empty list. I understand that the error is because I reached the end of my list, and that I need a base case here, but I'm not sure what is required. If I check to see if the list is null, and then return the list as my base case, it doesn't output anything.

Getting the following error:

> car: contract violation   expected: pair?   given: ()

Thanks for checking out my problem.

```
(define lst '( ("Apple" 1) ("Orange" 4)  ("Pear"3) ("Banana" 2)) )

(define name (lambda (m)
               (car m)
               ))

(define priority (lambda (m)
                   (car (cdr m))
                   ))

(define sortList
  (lambda (lst)
    (sort lst
       (lambda (x y)
        (<(priority x)(priority y))
       )
      )
    )
 )

(define printItem (lambda (m)

                      (display (name m))
                      (display " : ")
                      (display (priority m))
                      (display "\n")
                      )
  )

(define printQueue
  (lambda (lst)
    (printItem (car(sortList lst)))
    (printQueue (cdr (sortList lst)))
    )
  )

(printQueue lst)
```

Comment: Also, I tried "map" and was somewhat successful, only that it returned a bunch of "voids" at the end, which I don't really want.

Comment: Also, try not to format code as you would in (say) Java. Scheme/racket have their own formatting conventions that actually look pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must ensure that the list is not empty for the procedure to work, that's the base case. Also avoid sorting the list *twice* at every iteration! try this:

```
(define printQueue
  (lambda (lst)
    (unless (null? lst)
      (printItem (car lst))
      (printQueue (cdr lst)))))

(printQueue (sortList lst))
```

By the way, it'd be more idiomatic to use a `for-each` in this case:

```
(define (printQueue lst)
  (for-each printItem lst))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That certainly works! I'm wondering why "  (if(not(null? lst))" doesn't work, though. I was trying to do that before you answered, but it just returned the first item of the list.

Comment: In Racket an `if` _must_ have an else part, so if you didn't put one it'll fail. Alternatively, you could say `(when (not ...))`, but that's equivalent to using `unless`.